# My first attempt at K&R 2-3's hex to integer htoi()

Tags: c

I'm working through K&R on my own to learn C.

> 2-3 Write the function htoi(s), which converts a string of hexadecimal
>   digits (including an optional 0x or 0X) into it's equivalent integer value.
>   The allowable digits are 0 through 9, a through f, and A through F.

I've opted to convert each valid digit to it's 0-15 equivalent and ignore non valid characters.

I tried to not use anything not presented in these first 46 pages.

I'm using static input until I get htoi() correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int htoi(char s[]);
// hex alpha char to integer
// 0..1 and Aa - fF
int hatoi(char c);

int main()
{
    char s[] = "0xfff";
    int res; /* result */
    res = htoi(s);
    printf("%s = %d\n",s,res);
    return 0;
}

int hatoi(char c)
{
  int res;
  if (isdigit(c))
    res = c - '0';
  else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
    /* offset a..f to 10-14 */
    res = (c - '0')-39;
  else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
    /* offset a..f to 10-14 */
    res = (c - '0')-7;
  else
    res = 0;
  return res;
}

int htoi(char s[])
{
  int len,i,result,power,digit;
  result = power = 0;

  len = strlen(s)-1;

  for (i=len; i >= 0; --i) {
    digit = hatoi(s[i]);
    if (digit) {
      if (power == 0) {
        result += digit;
        power++;
      } else
        result += digit * power;
      power *= 16;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Am I close?  It seems to work alright.  I want to make sure I'm not learning bad habits and that I'm grasping what I should be by chapter 2.

Comment: You might want to try [StackExchange Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks - the SO code review will be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- Your code will not work if your string contains a `0` in the middle; consider the test you're doing on the return value of `hatoi`.
- The numbers `39` and `7` seem a bit magic.  It's clearer if you can derive them explicitly in code.
- It's good practice to always put code blocks after `if` or `else` in braces, even if it's just a single statement.
- Why not initialise `power` to be `1`?  That way, you don't need that special-case logic in your loop.

Comment: +1, but for the third one I'm with you only if there are comments between the `if` and the actual statement.

Answer (score 1):

- I'd use `int` for `hatoi()` parameter: `int hatoi(int ch);`
- You have no way to distinguish between a valid `'0'` and an invalid character in `hatoi()`.
- The `htoi()` function can be simplified quite a bit. For instance, the `if (digit)` test is unnecessary (you are looping from strlen-1 to the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

Is `isdigit` limited to 0-9, or are they affected by locale? Wouldn't want the latter.

`res = (c - '0')-39;` should be `res = (c - 'a')+10;`

`res = (c - '0')-7;` should be `res = (c - 'A')+10;`

<strike>Note that this only works on ASCII-based machines. Numbers and/or letters aren't sequential on EBCDIC machines.</strike>

The argument should be a `const` pointer.

`htoi` is very complicated. You should find `num = (num << 4) | digit;` very useful.

```
int htoi(const char *s)
{
   int result = 0;
   while (*s)
      result = ( result << 4 ) | hatoi(*(s++));
   return result;
}
```

You might want to check for overflow.

Comment: Numbers are sequential in EBCDIC.  In fact, the C standard mandates it.

Comment: a-f and A-F are sequential on EBCDIC. Sequentiality isn't guaranteed in all character sets though (but I know of no set where a-f / A-F aren't sequential).

Comment: bitwise operators are not yet introduced at this time in the book.

Comment: @Richard Holland, then `num = (num * 16) + digit;`

Answer (score 1):

```
int hatoi(char c); /*** I'd suggest a longer, descriptive name
                        such as parse_hexdigit ***/

int main()
{
    char s[] = "0xfff"; /*** Is this a good test case?
                             It is a palindrome with no numbers 0-9 ***/
    …
}

int hatoi(char c)
{
  int res;
  if (isdigit(c))
    res = c - '0';
  else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
    /* offset a..f to 10-14 */ /*** 10 - 15 ***/
    res = (c - '0')-39; /*** res = c - 'a' + 10 is clearer ***/
  else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
    /* offset a..f to 10-14 */
    res = (c - '0')-7; /*** res = c - 'A' + 10 is clearer ***/
  else
    res = 0;
  return res;
}

int htoi(char s[])
{
  int len,i,result,power,digit;
  result = power = 0;

  len = strlen(s)-1; /*** Check for overflow when you can ***/

  for (i=len; i >= 0; --i) { /*** Avoid iterating backwards ***/
    digit = hatoi(s[i]);
    if (digit) {
      if (power == 0) {
        result += digit;
        power++;
      } else /*** Use a consistent pattern of braces ***/
        result += digit * power;
      power *= 16;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

I would write it like this:

```
unsigned htoi( char *s ) {
    unsigned acc = 0;

    if ( * s != '0' ) return 0;
    ++ s;
    if ( * s != 'x' || * s != 'X' ) return 0;
    ++ s;

    /* Check that multiplication by 16 will not overflow */
    while ( acc < UINT_MAX / 16 ) {
        if ( * s >= '0' && * s <= '9' ) {
            acc *= 16;
            acc += * s - '0';
        } else if ( * s >= 'A' && * s <= 'F' ) {
            acc *= 16;
            acc += * s - 'A' + 10;
        } else if ( * s >= 'a' && * s <= 'f' ) {
            acc *= 16;
            acc += * s - 'a' + 10;
        } else {
            return acc; /* handles end of string or just end of number */
        }

        ++ s;
    }

    return acc;
}
```

Comment: How would I do this iterating forward - and by checking for overflow would I make sure len was >0?  Maybe make it an unsigned?

Comment: @Richard: See update. Checking for overflow would mean making sure the string is not long enough to contain more digits than an `int` can hold.

Comment: limits.h was introduced up to this point so perhaps I could check acc against UINT_MAX?

Comment: @Richard: Check against `UINT_MAX / 16`, yep that's just what it's for :v) .

Comment: I had originally iterated backwards because I thought I *HAD* to parse the hex string right to left for the math.  It works going left to right or right to left?

Comment: @Richard: Not only does left to right work, as you can see that approach requires fewer local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, this looks pretty good. I'll add some comments inline for the things I think you could improve.

```
int hatoi(char c)
{
  int res;
  if (isdigit(c))
    res = c - '0';
```

There's no real reason to create a `res` variable. You always return whatever you set in that variable, and never change it. Why not just replace `res = c - '0'` and the later `return res` with `return c - 0`?

```
  else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
    /* offset a..f to 10-14 */
    res = (c - '0')-39;
```

This seems somewhat convoluted. Why are you subtracting `'0'` and then `39`? It would be much more clear to say `(c - 'a') + 10`. Also, the comment is wrong, it should say `10-15`.

```
  result = power = 0;

  len = strlen(s)-1;

  for (i=len; i >= 0; --i) {
```

Your loop is running over the whole string; but in a hex string like `0xabcd`, the `0x` probably shouldn't be considered part of the number you are parsing. The way you are doing it, treating unknown characters as 0, it shouldn't matter for your test string, but if you other stuff at the beginning (like `1230xabcd`), you would get a fairly strange result. I would recommend checking that the first two characters actually are `0x` (probably returning `0` if not), and then looping down to `2` rather than down to `0`.

```
    digit = hatoi(s[i]);
    if (digit) {
```

You appear to only be increasing `power` if the digit is non-zero. Thus, for a number like `0x0102`, you would get 18, instead of the correct result 258. There's no need for the `if (digit)` check. If you want to return a sentinel from `hatoi` in the case of invalid characters in order to ignore them, I'd recommend returning `-1`, and then check `if (digit >= 0)`.

```
      if (power == 0) {
        result += digit;
        power++;
```

If you initialize `power` to `1` instead of `0`, you will not have to have this special case.

```
      } else
        result += digit * power;
      power *= 16;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple version to handle positive hexdigits

```c
int htoi(const char s[]) {
    unsigned int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if (s[0] == '0' && (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X')){
        i += 2;
    }
    int isValid = 1;  // check if hexdigit is valid
    for (; isValid; i++) {
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            n = 16 * n + (s[i] - '0');
        }
        else if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f') {
            n = 16 * n + (s[i] - 'a' + 10);
        }
        else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F') {
            n = 16 * n + (s[i] - 'A' + 10);
        }
        else {
            isValid = 0;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```